# Excel 2007 Ability to have other access the sheet with same format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created an excel spread sheet that fits exactly on my screen and saved it in a shared drive so my team mates can access it.  It has some macros and other sheets on the right side of the main spreadsheet.  The macros are used to jump from one spreadsheet to another.

When my team mate loaded the same spreadsheet, the spread sheet does not fit their screen and when I jump to the next spredsheet using the same coordinate, that is f5 AE1 for example, the spreadsheet does not fit exactly on the screen (but it does on my computer).

Also, the buttons with macros do not work.  What do I have to do in order to make it work in their computer?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Windows world it is not a good strategy to assume any specific screen resolution, because in Excel you can't really control the absolute position of items in the screen. Excel is built with the assumption, that it is up to the user to adjust document zoom, windows size and screen resolution. But if you insist, you can control any of these settings through VBA, although some of them might require more privileges (for instance the local policy can deny the user right to adjust the screen resolution) and in general it will require a lot of work from your side.
2. Macro execution is disabled in Excel by default. There are at least three ways to enable it: a) enable macro execution globally, b) put the worksheet in the "trusted" path (or make the path where the worksheet resides "trusted"), c) by clicking "yes" in the pop-up bar which asks whether run macros from this particular workbook this one time. Because of security concerns, it is by design impossible to alter the macro security policy through VBA. The user must to it himself manually (although I believe you can bypass it through 3-rd party automation tools like AutoIt, but I don't recommend it.)